# Undefined variable in shell script by using ssh

Tags: linux, r, shell, ssh

I use shell script to run R program as following:

```
host_list="server@com" Directory="/home/program/" ssh -f "$host_list" 'cd $Directory && nohup Rscript L_1.R> L_1_sh.txt'
```

But it always says

```
Directory: Undefined variable.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH does not propagate all your environment variables. You're only setting on the environment of the local client `ssh` program, not on the server side. As a hack, just stick it inside the commands that `ssh` is running remotely, instead of the pre-command environment setup.

```
host_list="server@com"  ssh -f "$host_list" 'Directory="/home/program/"; cd "$Directory" && nohup ...'
```

Here's a simpler version of the command that will let you test it without depending on your particular program setup.

```
ssh localhost Dir="/etc"; echo Dir is "$Dir"; cd "$Dir" && pwd && ps
```

Comment: I tried what you suggest. But it shows `Direcotory="/home/program: Command not found. Directory: Undefined variable".`

Comment: Sounds like maybe a typo: `Direcotory` is misspelled in your error message. And maybe a quote is missing?

Comment: I am sorry that I put `"`. The true output is `Directory=/home/program: Command not found. Directory:Undefined variable`.

Comment: Okay, that looks different. Maybe it's a shell syntax issue. What shell are you using on the remote machine? This solution will work for `bash` and `zsh`, but maybe not for other shells. You may need `set Directory="/home/program"` or something else instead of just `Directory="/home/program"`. And does the simplified version I posted work for you? That one I was able to test myself and confirm it works (for `bash` or `zsh`).

Comment: I tried what you let me to test. The output is following `The authenticity of host 'localhost (::1)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is be:6c:33:81:b5:be:f3:14:dc:ba:b0:a5:23:f0:46:ca.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'localhost' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.`

Comment: Actually, I have multiple hosts, and multiple directories and multiple programs. Since each line is very long which initialized by `ssh -f`, is there a way to put the names of multiple directories and the name of multiple programs at the begin of the shell script. I think it would be easier for me to edit it.

Comment: That "authenticity" warning is just what happens when you `ssh` to a new host for the first time. It's fine.

Comment: You could write a little shell script to build the strings for you. In bash or zsh, stick the variable names you want to propagate in a list, and then loop through them and build the `ssh` command string, and then call `ssh` from your script. And you could replace the multiple `set` commands with a single `env` call to make it a bit more concise. There's probably a better way but it's not occurring to me at the moment.

Comment: I am quite new about linux, especially about shell script. Can you edit the shell script for me as an template [test.sh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/37s7el5yc1b6c1i/test.sh?dl=0?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you can try those:

1. In bash single quotes `''` does not repace variables [Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Single-Quotes.html)
2. Try to use `${Directory}` or change the variable name (maybe is
   reserved)

Comment: I tried to change the name of address, but it still does not work. For 1, what do you suggest me to do about it? I should use `' '`

Comment: Why you shouldn't use `""` ? have you tried to use double quotes and enclosing sensible parts in single quotes, or escaping it?

Comment: #1 should work: by switching to `""` double quotes, the `$Directory` variable in the remote command will get substituted with the path locally before being sent to the server, so it won't matter if `$Directory` doesn't get set on the server side, as long as the program itself doesn't depend on it.